# Ajax with Jquery - Callback not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jquery-callback

I have tried so many things, cannot figure this out, I am using this code, and I know that the start is working, because the script it connects to sticks some info in the db, but the callback never runs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', "#reply_submit", function() {
            var formData = $('#reply').serialize();


            $.post("newpost.php",formData, function(data){
                    alert("hi");
             }, "json");
    });
```

});

My form's id is "reply" and the button I am using to submit it is "reply-submit", just to make sure those things are clear.

It also doesn't work if I remove that last "json" thing btw.

Comment: whats the error message you are getting?

Comment: check what error you get in console...

Comment: Do you have a URL we can see? If you are using fire bug are you getting any errors? What kind of feedback do you see under the Net tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs for [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), it says this about the callback:

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>   A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

If it's not getting called, it means that request did not succeed. There is probably an error in `newpost.php` (sometime after the data insert, but before it would normally exit).

You can also catch error conditions by using the long-form [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of the post shorthand:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'newpost.php',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this was it, my backend script seemed to be throwing up some errors all of a sudden.. to be honest it's a bit of a blur right now, but yeah, I think this was the problem :|

Answer (score 1):

When you click, the form is also being submitted the standard way. Modify your click handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#reply_submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit event
  var formData = $('#reply').serialize();
  // ...
});
```

Although I think `document.body` should be a valid node to wrap in jQuery, I've also modified it to the more commonly used `document`.

On that note, if the form is never destroyed by an Ajax event or other DOM modification, you could bind to `#reply` instead of `document` (or `body`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm simply assuming that you want to submit a form without reloading the whole page.
Based on that assumption, following code will serve the purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//on form submit event
$('form#reply').submit(function(){
    $.post('newpost.php',$(this).serialize(),function(){
        alert("Message or do something with the response data if you are expecting one");
    });

    //prevent default action
    return false;   
});

});
```

Please ignore the post if this is not the functionality you are looking for in your project.